# Having OpenBox running, what gnome apps to start in the autostart.sh to have full gnome support (except panels and so on)

Tags: ubuntu, openbox

I have switched from Gnome to OpenBox.

In OpenBox I start some programs at startup by calling them in `~/.config/openbox/autostart.sh`. What part-programs of gnome to call here, to start OpenBox with full Gnome support?

What I do not need is that new taskbar to the left and the panels.

Starting the so called "openbox-gnome-session" does not work properly - I get some kind of fullscreen-nautilus then...